# What GNOME/Xfce based distros work out of the box with Nvidia cards?

Tags: linux, nvidia-geforce, linux-distributions

I'm trying out linux distros. My desktop has an Nvidia GTX 460 card. Does any one have recommendations for 64 bit linux distros - derived from either Debian/Ubuntu or Redhat- which have 3d hardware acceleration support for Nvidia cards out of the box? (No Ubuntu please - I don't care for Unity)

The distro shouldn't have "idealogical" issues with closed/binary drivers from Nvidia! (This was true of Redhat earlier)

I've tried out linux mint 17.1 so far, and it was frequently freezing and locking up the GUI. It does work fine on my older Core i5 laptop running intel graphics.

Any help would be appreciated!

-Thanks

ps: I don't want to work with VMs.

Comment: Given its proprietary nature; "work out of the box" might be uncommon, I'd suggest to stick with a distro you prefer and follow a tutorial to enable the NVIDIA drivers on that distro.

Comment: Just a BTW, most distros come with a number of desktop choices.  No need to rule out Ubuntu only on the basis of Unity; you can get it (or derivatives), with pretty much any desktop you like.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried out Xubuntu. I'm quite pleased at how it looks and feels.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know due to license issues none of those carry native (ootb support)  however

For Ubuntu /Debian (or based on):   its a  simple nvidia or edgers ppa add if the "latest" ---while not always best drivers are not sourced by default.

For Redhat (or based on):  you need to install nvidia-337-* or possibly newer